# Horizontal fixed navbar on twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On new version of twitter bootstrap, all the examples shows a sidebar fixin on left top side of the page when scrolling, but older versions I remember used to display this sidebar after the principal navbar fixed on top of the page.

On new version is there a way to fixed top this "sidebar" nav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `affix` property.

See the full details in the documentation: http://rc.getbootstrap.com/javascript.html#affix

Comment: This allows you to specify with css how `affix-top` appears, and also what the offset is (i.e. when it does it become fixed in location).

Comment: I could affix it.. the problem still. I want the nav to be horizontal, not vertical.

Comment: You can still do that! It simply fixes it, and you can then style it as you wish with CSS.