# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Navbar not horizontal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm fiddlin' around with bootstrap 3. I'm trying to make an horizontal navbar except it doesn't turn out horizontal. I thought the navbar should be horizontal out of the box, do I perhaps need some additional css?

I tried to make a navbar copying code from the bootstrap documentation like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">            
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FxkZT/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontal fixed navbar on twitter bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989495/horizontal-fixed-navbar-on-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FxkZT/7/)

Your code is for BootStrap 2 and needs to be changed. In bootstrap 3:

1. `<a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>` becomes `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>`
2. `<ul class="nav">` becomes `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`
3. No more need for `<div class="navbar-inner">`

More info in the doc [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

Comment: You're right, I was actually looking at the wrong documentation. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/FxkZT/5/

I just added this little bit of CSS, check it out and let me know if it works for you:

CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

.navbar .nav > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* Internet Explorer 7 compatibility */
    *zoom:1;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```