# Twitter Bootstrap Navbar not displaying as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap and defined a navbar

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">  
    <div class="navbar-inner">  
        <div class="container">  
            <ul class="nav">  
                <li class="active">  
                     <a class="brand" href="#">w3resource</a>  
                </li>  
               <li>
                   <a href="#">About</a>
               </li>  
              <li>
                 <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
              </li>  
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>  
          </ul> 
       </div>  
   </div>  
</div>
```

I included the bootstrap css files, jquery and the bootstrap js files. The navbar is displayed as indicated by the image below.

[image]

This is strange because the other elements on the page seems to style just fine using bootstrap, have a look at the image below

[image]

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: which version are you using

Comment: Can you share your website to find the error?

Comment: Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC Version 2.0.0

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally got the navbar to display as expected, this is what I did.

- I uninstalled twitter bootstrap and re-installed using NuGet to make sure I have the
  latest version (Version 3.0.0).
- The syntax to create a navbar for bootstrap version 2.0.0 and 3.0.0 is different. Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191177/twitter-bootstrap-3-navbar-not-horizontal) that explains the difference.

After installing the newest version and updating the syntax, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the container class to container fluid:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"> <a class="brand" href="#">w3resource</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">About</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Portfolio</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Contact</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CrNPK/1/

Comment: This still didn't do the trick. I manually downloaded bootstrap version 3.0.0 and replaced the css and javascript files that was installed using NuGet. Now the navbar shows as expected but it is not responding when I click on the dropdowns.

Comment: Have you see the fiddle? Does it match your expected result?